# Flutter : How to implement rating bar without rating action

Tags: flutter, dart, ratingbar

I have some products and each one has his rating value ( like 4.2 , 4 , 3.5 , etc)
and I want to display this values with rating bar like that

[image]

and this is my code for this part

```
Align(
 alignment:Alignment.topLeft,
  child:SmoothStarRating(
    allowHalfRating:false,
     starCount:5,
     rating: adminAcceptStatusAdd[index]['rate'].toDouble(),
     size: 20.0,
     isReadOnly:false,
     color: Colors.yellow,
     borderColor:Colors.yellow,
     filledIconData:Icons.star,
     halfFilledIconData:Icons.star_half,
     defaultIconData:Icons.star_border,
     spacing: .5,
     ),
     )
```

now I have two problem first one the rating bar allowing the user to change value rate so I want to make it just for showing
and the second problem i can't convert the value from api from string to double value I'm trying

```
adminAcceptStatusAdd[index]['rate'].toDouble()
```

but it didn't work
so can anyone help me please !

Comment: For the first problem, have you tryed to apply a click and a setState to change the icons for a full colored star?
For the second double.parse(adminAcceptStatusAdd[index]['rate'])

Comment: Try setting [`isReadOnly`](https://pub.dev/documentation/smooth_star_rating/latest/smooth_star_rating/SmoothStarRating/isReadOnly.html) to `true`, maybe? Also, we have no way of knowing what the type of "the value from api" is.

Comment: Could you add your SmoothStarRating Widget?
Also what does adminAcceptStatusAdd[index]['rate'] print ?

Comment: @AlbertoSáezVela I'm trying your solution now

Comment: @Riwen your solution helped me in my first problem thank you , and the type from api is string

Comment: @AntoninGAVREL print that : string not a subtype of double

Comment: Try [`double.Parse`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/double/parse.html), then.

Comment: @AlbertoSáezVela your solution work perfectly thanks for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For parse double from string:

```
double.parse(adminAcceptStatusAdd[index]['rate'])
```